# A Visual C++ Project for Linking Without Compiling

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to create a vc++ project that will link several libraries together, without first compiling anything.
I created an empty project, added Additional Dependencies in the Linker options, but when I try to build it I get the following:

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: sde-mix-mt, Configuration: Release x64 ------
1>Build started 2/6/2013 11:32:49 PM.
1>_PrepareForClean:
1>  Deleting file "x64\Release\sde-mix-mt.lastbuildstate".
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Creating "x64\Release\sde-mix-mt.unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
1>FinalizeBuildStatus:
1>  Deleting file "x64\Release\sde-mix-mt.unsuccessfulbuild".
1>  Touching "x64\Release\sde-mix-mt.lastbuildstate".
1>
1>Build succeeded.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:00.04
========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Although it says `Build succeeded` it didn't actually build anything (check the time elapsed).

Comment: Yes, that looks like an empty project.  Nothing to link if there's nothing compiled to link to.  Pretty unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: I am trying to make a project for linking purposes only: I want to link several (static) libraries together into a DLL. The libraries are  built from other project.